# Crystax get linking error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to compile my code with Crystax because NDK does not have C++ exceptions but when I tried to compile my code with Crystax I get this error (it works fine with standard NDK):

```
std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::ios_base'
```

I already tried to add `-lstdc++` to my makefile.

How can I get this to build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using APP_STL := gnustl_static in application.mk will solve this problem.